# Pandas: Assign value based on value in another row

Tags: python, pandas

I have the 3 columns data frame: page_number, line_number, text.

I want to create another column prev_text which contains text from previous page, the same line number eg:

For page 3, line 10 I want to have value from page 2, line 10 if such page & line exist.

At the moment I build 2 dimensional text array indexed by page and line. Next I use apply with function which refers to this two dimensional array.

Is there any better and faster way for making such assignment in Pandas?

I hope sort by line_number, page_number can work with other pandas function here.

Comment: I think you should have a look at df.shift(). You could shift the text column so that its value is in line with the previous page.....shift only with condition if page&line exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
import pandas as pd

df =  pd.DataFrame({'page_num': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4], 
                'line_num': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1], 
                'text': ['apple', 'banana', 'car', 
                          'dog', 'egg', 'fire', 
                         'goat', 'house', 'ink',
                         'jet']})
```

So `df` is

```
    page_num  line_num  text
0   1         1         apple
1   1         2         banana
2   1         3         car
3   1         4         dog 
4   2         1         egg 
5   2         2         fire
6   3         1         goat
7   3         2         house 
8   3         3         ink
9   4         1         jet
```

Then:

```
df['prev_page_num'] = df.groupby('line_num')['page_num'].shift(1, fill_value=0)
df_consecutive = df[df['page_num'] == df['prev_page_num'] + 1]
df['prev_text'] = df_consecutive.groupby('line_num').apply(lambda x: x['text'].shift(1)).droplevel(0)
df.sort_values(by=['page_num', 'line_num'], inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

which leaves us with `df`

```
    page_num    line_num    text    prev_page_num   prev_text
0   1           1           apple   0               NaN
1   1           2           banana  0               NaN
2   1           3           car     0               NaN
3   1           4           dog     0               NaN
4   2           1           egg     1               apple
5   2           2           fire    1               banana
6   3           1           goat    2               egg
7   3           2           house   2               fire
8   3           3           ink     1               NaN
9   4           1           jet     3               goat
```

There's probably a very clever way to do this by listing `connected_components` in a graph, but I'll leave that to someone else!

Comment: I changed your code in the following way group by line_num only and fix name to droplevel (pandas 1.3.4) -  after that I receive what I expected - Thank you: 

df['prev_text'] = df.groupby(['line_num']).apply(lambda x: x['text'].shift(1)).droplevel(0)

Comment: Oh yes, of course. I've updated my answer now. I've just noticed though - is row 8 in the output correct? Should `prev_text` for this row be NaN also, as there is no line 3 on page 2?

Comment: Row 8 should be Nan.  I think about adding something like: df.loc[df['page_num'].shift(1) != df['page_num'] - 1, 'prev_text] = NaN. Not sure if possible to add such condition in groupby statement.

Comment: You can (kind of) incorporate this in a `groupby` if we add in a `prev_page_num` column, as per my updated answer

Comment: Assuming df is in any state, you need move sort_by at the begining to work correctly. I changed fill value to -1, as my pages starts from 0 which is frequentn in language with 0-base indexes. Not sure if final reset_index is necessary, as it can broken in the futre any other inexes which are not default one - but I am new to Pandas so not sure about it.

Comment: Ah yes ok. I was making a guess at what format your data was in, but yes the `groupby`s and adding the `prev_page_num` column are the most important parts. The sorting and re-indexing are just for tidying up